# MySQL Query Take much time for 2600 records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

**Table Structures:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ebay_items` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `item_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_low` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_mid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_max` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_with_sign` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shipping_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `shipping_with_sign` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `variation_array` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `image_array` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_array` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `step_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `archived` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `archived_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5765 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `amazon_items` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `asin` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `related_ebay_item_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `item_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_low` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_mid` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `main_image_max` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `buy_box_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `buy_box_price_with_sign` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lowest_other_sellers_price` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `other_number_of_seller` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `variation_array` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_array` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `step_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `archived` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `archived_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7398 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
Create Table

CREATE TABLE `item_attributes` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amazon_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estimated_profit` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `refresh_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `import_items_logs` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ebay_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amazon_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
SELECT ei.id
     , ei.item_id
     , ei.item_url
     , ei.title
     , ei.main_image_low
     , ei.price
     , ei.price_with_sign
     , ei.shipping_price
     , ei.shipping_with_sign
     , ei.quantity
     , ei.brand
     , ei.model
     , ei.upc
     , ei.step_number
     , ei.archived
     , ei.archived_number
     , ei.user_id
     , ei.created_at
     , ei.updated_at
     , ai.id amazon_id
     , ai.asin
     , ai.item_url amazon_item_url
     , ai.title amazon_title
     , ai.main_image_low amazon_low_image
     , ai.buy_box_price_with_sign
     , ai.lowest_other_sellers_price
     , ai.other_number_of_seller
     , ai.category_array 
     , ai.status amazon_status
     , ia.sku 
     , ia.list_price 
     , ia.min_price 
     , ia.max_price 
     , ia.estimated_profit 
     , ia.status attr_status  
     , ia.added_time attr_added_time
     , ia.refresh_time attr_refresh_time
     , l.status import_status
     , l.tag import_tag 
  FROM ebay_items ei
  JOIN amazon_items ai
    ON ai.related_ebay_item_id = ei.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN item_attributes ia 
    ON ia.amazon_id = ai.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN import_items_logs l
    ON l.ebay_id = ei.id 
 WHERE ei.user_id = 1 
   AND ei.archived =2
 GROUP 
    BY ei.id
```

I'm trying to get item and additional details and Those are in separated tables

There are **4 tables** 
ebay_items, amazon_items, item_attributes, import_items_logs
This what i want as result,

1. ebay_items and amazon_items must be matched (ebay_items.id =
   amazon_items.related_ebay_item_id)
2. also item_attributes (amazon_items.id = item_attributes.amazon_id)
   and import_items_logs (ebay_items.id = import_items_logs.ebay_id)
   records need if any records exist

This is my query when i ran on local it's takes 50+sec or amazon server it's take 12sec to finish. What's wrong im doing here. Total records is 2600. i don't know why it's too slow

Query Explain

````
    id  select_type  table   type    possible_keys  key      key_len  ref                                        rows  Extra                                                   
------  -----------  ------  ------  -------------  -------  -------  ---------------------------------------  ------  --------------------------------------------------------
     1  SIMPLE       ai      ALL     (NULL)         (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)                                     4277  Using temporary; Using filesort                         
     1  SIMPLE       ei      eq_ref  PRIMARY        PRIMARY  8        other_rp-tool-2.ai.related_ebay_item_id       1  Using where                                             
     1  SIMPLE       ia      ALL     (NULL)         (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)                                     3134  Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)         
     1  SIMPLE       l       ALL     (NULL)         (NULL)   (NULL)   (NULL)                                     6076  Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join)  ```
````

Comment: Missing indexes, probably

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the complete DDL of the tables including the indexes and show the plan.

Comment: Also, please remove as many selected columns as possible from the query while still having the problem: By not taking the time to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the query is mostly noise, making it harder to answer and of must less value to future visitors.

Comment: Be aware that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: For further help, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And note that, as well as the above, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: I did explain what i can, But still it's seems closed thread.

Comment: @ÄRÂmmãřŻąîñh: please add an [explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-performance-explain.html) for this query. Paste the results of that into the post, using the code formatting tool. Thanks.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but it takes more votes. When you ask a question about query optimization, we need some details about your tables before we can make a good answer. You should share the table definitions, because otherwise we must guess at your columns and data types and indexes. Also please provide the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT...` which shows how your MySQL optimizer is currently using indexes. Here's an example of a query optimization question that includes the needed information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674471/how-to-optimze-this-mysql-simple-query

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` command is a way to get the MySQL optimizer to tell you how it plans to execute the query, before it really executes it. Read docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html or https://www.eversql.com/mysql-explain-example-explaining-mysql-explain-using-stackoverflow-data/

Comment: Thank you for adding the EXPLAIN. I see a couple of the rows indicate that your joins are not using indexes ("Using join buffer" means it must compare to every row in the joined table, instead of using an index to search only matching rows). This is good news because the query can probably be improved by adding a couple of well-chosen indexes.

Comment: Thank you for advice and approved to reopen.

Comment: `alter table ebay_items add key bk1 (user_id, archived); alter table item_attributes add key bk2 (amazon_id); alter table import_items_logs add key bk3 (ebay_id); alter table amazon_items add key bk4 (related_ebay_item_id);`

Comment: @BillKarwin Excellent, It's working so fast, Can you explain about your query, thank you

Comment: It's too much to explain in a comment, but I suggest you view (for free) this presentation I did about **How to Design Indexes, Really**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU and here are the slides: https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really