# How to optimze this Mysql simple query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This query is taking 450ms

```
SELECT `u`.`user_id`, `c`.`company`
FROM `users` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
WHERE `u`.`user_id` = 'search_term' 
  OR `u`.`lname` LIKE 'search_term%'    
  OR `u`.`email` LIKE 'search_term%'        
  OR `c`.`company` LIKE 'search_termeo%'
```

**tables:**

- users (260250 rows)
- companies (570 rows)

**structures:**

***- users:***

```
   CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `region_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `fname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `lname` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `phone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
     KEY `idx_lname` (`lname`),
     KEY `idx_email` (`email`),
     UNIQUE KEY `unq_region_id_email` (`region_id`, `email`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

***- companies:***

```
 CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vat_num` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
   KEY `idx_company` (`company`) USING BTREE,
   CONSTRAINT `users_companies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The result of explain query
 [image: Query explain]

I think **450ms** is too much for such query and such little amount of data
and I want to know if there is somthing to optimize

query run in querious v3 under iMac 2017, 3,4 GHz, 16Go

Mysql: 5.7.26 on MAMP pro v5.7

Comment: What indexes have you added? You can try this https://www.eversql.com (I'm not affiliated with them)

Comment: Are you accessing this via a server side script or running the query in the DB itself?

Comment: look you join tow complete tables and then you reduce the number of rows., try tow reduce to ionly the relevant users and companies.

Comment: Can you try changing your ON clause to LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` LIKE `search_term`. The c.user_id in your ON clause and u.user_id = search term are redundant.

Comment: thanks guys for your replies. @Alec, all indexes & constraints are in the code snippet of my question :)

Comment: @alpharomeo, running the query directly in my local db via the app Querious, similar to Sequelpro

Comment: @Mech, i tried your solution, with `c.user_id LIKE search_term`it returns timeout, and if i use `c.user_id = search_term` it's pretty fast but doesn't return all the results (results from table companies are missing)

Comment: OK - this is what I did when I had a very large dataset that I needed to traverse. I broke the query down in to two and returned the results separately and merged the values. Given this was in a Web app - but you could try that here. Also, as yours in Innodb - you could try increasing the innodb buffer size - but please remember the "here be dragons" rule and you could screw up your performance if you are not careful.

Comment: An index on `email` or `lname` may help. `unq_region_id_email` will not because your query does not filter with `region_id` (earlier fields in the key must be used to take advantage of later fields).

Comment: @Uueerdo the indices were alredy set. I forgot to add them in the snippet code, but as you can see, they are present in explain query (the attached image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` conditions when not on the same field or range based (such as `<`, `>`, `LIKE`) really decrease MySQL's ability to take advantage of indexes; you can restructure queries by breaking them down into separate simpler ones that you can then UNION. Separating it out like this allows MySQL to take advantage of a different index of each query within the UNIONs

```
SELECT `u`.`user_id`, `c`.`company`
FROM `users` AS `u` LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
WHERE `u`.`user_id` = 'search_term' 
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT `u`.`user_id`, `c`.`company`
FROM `users` AS `u` LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
WHERE `u`.`lname` LIKE 'search_term%'    
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT `u`.`user_id`, `c`.`company`
FROM `users` AS `u` LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
WHERE `u`.`email` LIKE 'search_term%'
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT `u`.`user_id`, `c`.`company`
FROM `users` AS `u` INNER JOIN `companies` AS `c` ON `c`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`
WHERE `c`.`company` LIKE 'search_termeo%'
;
```

Also, note that I changed the last one's JOIN to an INNER since any condition on the right-hand table of a LEFT JOIN (that isn't "without a match from that table") is basically an INNER JOIN anyway.

`UNION DISTINCT` is used to prevent records that satisfied multiple conditions from being repeated, however... if `companies.company` is not unique (i.e. company id 1 called "Blah" and company id 12 also called "Blah") then those will also be merged where they would not be in your original query; if it is a potential issue, that can be remedied by also including company_id in each `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks @Uueerdo, this is a very clear explanation, and the query is now very fast. another thing I don't understand much in the explain query is why the key of users table is NULL.

Comment: @volcaniCody Understanding MySql's EXPLAIN results has always been kind of a weak point for me, but my guess would be (assuming you're talking about the explain for your original query) is that it indicates MySQL could find no good index for the combination of conditions, so was doing a full table scan (basically going through every single row and checking the conditions that way) rather than use any index to narrow down the possible rows to check against.